# ASP.NET MVC SelectList from Viewmodel not populating SelectedItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel with multiple SelectLists defined for a view, and I'm trying to create shared SelectLists for things that are commonly used, like a list of states. When the SelectList in the viewmodel is populated I can see that the SelectedItem is being set correctly, but it's not populating in the view.

In the viewmodel:

```
[Display(Name = "State")]
public int StateID { get; set; }

public SelectList States { get; set; }
```

In the controller:

```
staff.States = StatesMenu(db.TenantRepos.StateID); //setting default value
```

SelectList:

```
public static SelectList StatesMenu(int? selected)
    {
        SelectList _states = new SelectList(db.States.OrderBy(o => o.Code).Select(x => new StateMenuVM { ID = x.ID, Code = x.Code }), "ID", "Code", selected);
        return _states;
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID, Model.States)
```

As such, the selectlist doesn't have a selected item when I run the view. If I do this manually, the selected item obviously works:

```
staff.StateID = db.TenantRepos.StateID;
```

I'm confused about why the SelectList isn't being created with that item already selected, since I'm setting that value in the new SelectList, and it's passing through correctly to staff.States.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: in selected variable there is id or code?

Comment: Yes, the ID is there and it's definitely being passed to staff.States correctly as the SelectedValue.

Comment: I am not sure but could you call `.ToList()` to the construtcor of your Seleclist at the first parameter in your static method StatesMenu?

Comment: @jlkmpls - DropDownListFor does not use the Selected value of SelectList, so it doesn't matter if the value is passed to your function that builds the SelectList.  It only matters if the first parameter to DropDownListFor contains the selected value.

Comment: @Erik Thank you! If you leave this as an answer instead I can vote for it.

Out of curiosity, do you know which controls do actually take the SelectedValue parameter of SelectList into account?

Comment: @lnanikian I thought that was it, but apparently not. Same result.